# RotateControl is not showing in Google Maps API javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Here is the current code:

```
var mapOpt = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-3.10056,-59.9431),
zoom: 12,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
rotateControl: true
};
mapGoogle = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"),mapOpt);

<div id="gmap" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"></div>
```

I Tryed to set panControl, tilted too and nothing happend

Answer (score 0):

Per [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification):

> - rotateControl enables/disables the appearance of a Rotate control for controlling the orientation of 45° imagery. By default, the control's presence is determined by the presence or absence of 45° imagery for the given map type at the current zoom and location. You may alter the control's behavior by setting the map's rotateControlOptions to specify the RotateControlOptions to use. **You cannot make the control appear if no 45° imagery is currently available**.

The rotate control is only available where the imagery is available and when the map is zoomed in close enough.

It is not available where your map is located.  It is available in New York City at zoom level 18 [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/bhsL8465/)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var mapOpt = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.7127837, -74.0059413 /* -3.10056,-59.9431 */ ),
    zoom: 18,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  };
  mapGoogle = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("gmap"), mapOpt);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);
```

```css
html,
body,
#gmap {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="gmap" style="width: 100%;height: 100%"></div>
```